# Unable to send all old mysql database data to kafka via Debezium

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I want to send data to kafka using debezium mysql connector.
I am only able to send any news updates that are happening from the time connector was started.
How do I send all previous data without running any update operation on the tables.
Is there any such property which I can add to my connector config.

Following is my current config.

```
curl --location --request POST "http://10.110.11.23:80/connectors" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp.document_service.connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "minimal",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "database.hostname": "mynode.server",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "my_user",
    "database.password": "DsFFERD",
    "database.server.name": "cdc.fkw.supply.mp",
    "database.whitelist": "document_service",
    "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl":true,
    "heartbeat.interval.ms":5000,
    "table.whitelist": "document_service.DocumentDetails, document_service.Documents",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "10.49.115.249:9092,10.48.130.211:9092,10.54.178.121:9092,10.53.4.69:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.cdc.fkw.supply.mp.document_service23122021",
    "errors.tolerance" : "all",
    "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": 5000,
    "include.schema.changes": "true"
  }
}'
```

=========== Added details =============

I will tell you what I did.

So when I faced this issue with my connector,

1. I deleted the connector and deleted the history topics and the table topics in kafka.
2. Recreated the history topic with unlimited retention and other table topics in kafka
3. Now I have everything clean
4. Now when I create a connector with initial or when_needed snapshot mode, It pops out some strange error.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The db history topic is missing. You may attempt to recover it by reconfiguring the connector to SCHEMA_ONLY_RECOVERY
```

So when I try to recreate the connector with as suggested in error with schema_only_recovery it says

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not find first log file name in binary log index file Error code
```

Comment: I would search for why you might be getting `Could not find first log file name in binary log index file` as this seems like a database client error

Comment: What happens when I delete the connector and all kafka topics belonging to them?
Still does the connector has details stored somewhere?

Comment: Other than the Debezium history topic, there's the three internal Kafka Connect topics that actually store/manage the connector information, yes.

Comment: I am afraid but, how or where to start to search about " database client error "
What can be the possibility?

Comment: I haven't used Debezium with MySQL, but the error seems to be coming from the database server rather than Kafka Connect

Comment: e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139131/error-1236-could-not-find-first-log-file-name-in-binary-log-index-file